# Use $.getscript can't recognize the script with jQuery UI "dialog({})"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In page A.html, I have import the jQuery base file "jquery-1.4.2.min.js" & "jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js"

In the page, I also write `$("#dialog").dialog({……});` with `<div class="dialog">……</div>`

There exist a `<input>` button to open the dialog. I write the function in another js file "test.js":

```
$("input").click(function(){$("#dialog").dialog("open");})
```

then I use the `$.getscript` to load the js file: `$.getscript("test.js")`

But in finally result, I click the input button page can't open the dialog. Also Firebug alert error

It seems that the `.dialog("open")` method can't be recognized.

Why it can not be recognized? How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If your div really has `class="dialog"`, you should use `$('.dialog')`. Alternatively, use `<div id="dialog">` and `$('#dialog')`.

Comment: This is not  the original code,because I need ask question here,so I change the code in a hurry,……

Answer (score 0):

*Usually* this is caused by 1 of 2 things:

- jQuery UI **isn't** properly loaded, so none of the widget methods are defined
- jQuery UI **is** properly loaded, but you included jQuery core *again* later in the page, which wipes out any plugins

Check for either of these...in my experience that's what causes plugin-not-defined methods *most* of the time.